# Как поменять редактор на emacs в Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

Я пробовал через `select-editor` поменять, но этот способ не подходит так как нужно запускать emacs так: `emacs -nw`. Где можно такие настройки выставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если в mc вы уже редактировали файлы, то в вашем домашнем каталоге есть файл **.selected_editor**. В этом файле прописывается редактор, используемый mc. Добавьте или измените параметр **SELECTED_EDITOR**:

   SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs -nw"

при этом emacs будет запускаться в консоли

2. если вы еще не редактировали файлы, то при нажатии  mc предложит вам сделать выбор редактора вот из такого списка (для примера):

   Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.

   1. /bin/ed
   2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
   3. /usr/bin/code
   4. /usr/bin/emacs24
   5. /usr/bin/mcedit
   6. /usr/bin/vim.basic
   7. /usr/bin/vim.gnome
   8. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

   Choose 1-8 [2]:

в списке у меня для выбора emacs нужно нажать 4

при этом emacs будет запускаться с gui

3. можно удалить файл **.selected_editor**, тогда действия будут аналогичны пункту 2

Answer (score 0):

убрать галку "встроенный редактор" в настройках mc. Задать в профайле EDITOR='emacs -nw'.